# i want to used multiselect in angular js 2?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-multiselect

I am working on angular js 2,I Want to used multi-select in my project. I was using bootstrap multi-select, but bootstrap multi-select not worked properly.Please, give me any Solution?

```
setTimeout(() => { 
    $('#roleteamSelectid').multiselect({ 
            enableFiltering: false, 
            includeSelectAllOption: true, 
            selectAllJustVisible: false, 
            numberDisplayed: 1 
});
```

Comment: Have you added the links of bootstrap and jquery in index.html file correctly inside your angular application ?

Comment: yes, bootstrap multiselect used with settimeout, because of settimeout data not populate correctly or control not bind correctly.

Comment: setTimeout(() => {
            $('#roleteamSelectid').multiselect({
                enableFiltering: false,
                includeSelectAllOption: true,
                selectAllJustVisible: false,
                numberDisplayed: 1
            });

Comment: Is the bootstrap multi select working with static data inside your template?

Comment: yes, but not working with dynamic data.

Comment: <select required name="roleteamSelectid" id="roleteamSelectid" class="form-control roleteamSelect" multiple="multiple">                        
                                        <option  class="Test" *ngFor="let item of teams"  selected="{{ item.Selected ? 'selected' : '' }}" value="{{item.Team_Id}}">
                                            {{item.TeamName}}
                                        </option>